# Is "SH512" secure if using RSA?

Tags: security, hash, rsa

I wanted to sign some data(string not file) and was checking what methods and technics are secure. My searching results were interesting because it seems The SHA1, SHA256, and SHA512 functions are no longer considered secure and have been broken.

Now my question is that, If they are not secure why are available in .net?

And if I use SHA512 to sign my data with RSA this is not secure too? I'm asking Because we using public and private keys and hackers can not access the private key.

```
 using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
          //...
          // Sign the data, using SHA512 as the hashing algorithm 
            signedBytes = rsa.SignData(originalData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"));
         //...
        }
```

Please offer me an alternative algorithm or ..to sign my data on the public network in .NET.

Comment: SHA-1 was found to be insecure, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). What are your references for claiming that SHA-256 and SHA-512 should not be used for digital signatures for security reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collision resistance in SHA1 is [broken](https://shattered.io/). However, that's not the case with SHA256 and SHA512, those are still considered secure as cryptographic hash functions.

An important point is that you don't "use SHA512 to sign" data. SHA is a hash function, it takes an input of arbitray length, and maps it to a fixed length output while having certain [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Properties).

The way it's related to signing data is that assymetric key cryptography is slow for large amounts of data. Instead of running your signing algorithm (RSA) for the whole piece of data, you can first create a hash of it, and sign that instead. Assuming the second preimage resistance and collision resistance properties of a proper crypto hash function, it will be infeasible to find another input that has the same hash value, which from the signature's perspective means it will not be possible to find another input for which the signature is valid.

As SHA1 is broken, using that to create the hash that will be signed, you cannot have these assumptions, ie. it might be possible to create another piece of data for which the original signature is still valid.

So in short, using SHA256 or SHA512 as the hash algorithm for RSA signatures is still secure, but SHA1 is not.

As for why SHA1 is still in .net, for backwards compatibility I guess. You can't just remove the whole thing from the framework, a lot of old stuff might still need it. It does not mean you should be using it though.